# Delete nodes at prime indexes in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm doing some exercisese with linked lists and came across this one : I need to write a function that deletes the nodes at indexes that are prime numbers in a linked list. For example, if the linked list is :

```
6->3->5->2->7->1->NULL
```

the returned list must be :

```
6->2->1->NULL.
```

I've written functions `delete(Node* list)` and `isPrime(int n)` to help me with the function I need to write. But I keep getting a segmentation fault. The `delete(Node* list)` function and `isPrime(int n)` function work, I believe the problem is in `primes(Node* list)`.

Here's my code :

```
typedef struct Node {
int data;
struct Node* next;
}Node;

void printList(Node* list) {
    if(list->next == NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", list->data);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d ", list->data);
        printList(list->next);
    }
}

Node* addLast(Node* list, int x) {
    Node* head = list;
    if(head == NULL) {
        Node* new = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new->data = x;
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }
    else {

        while(head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }

        Node* new = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new->data = x;
        new->next = NULL;

        head->next = new;
        return list;
    }
}

void delete(int n, Node* head) {
    Node* temp = head;
    if(n == 0) {
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else {
            int i;
            for(i = 0 ; i < (n-2); i++) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            Node* temp1 = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp1->next;
            free(temp1);
    }
}

bool isPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 0;
    if(n == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    else {
        int i;
        for(i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if(n%i == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Node* primes(Node* list) {
    Node* temp = list;
    int i = 1;
    while(temp != NULL) {

       if(isPrime(i)) {
          delete(i-1, temp);
       }
       else { i++; }
       temp = temp->next;

    }
    return list;
}

int main() {
    int n, st, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    Node* head = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &st);
        head = addLast(head, st);
    }  
    printList(head);

    printList(primes(head));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void delete(int n, Node* head) { ... head = ... }` very likely makes no sense; If you deleted the first element of the list, then the head of the list needs to be retargeted to another element, and the signature of `delete` should therefore be something like `void delete(int n, Node **head)`.

Comment: @StephanLechner. OP is deleting nodes at indices which are prime.Since `1` is not prime, that is not going to be a problem.

Comment: After you delete a node, the numbers of the following nodes will no longer be correct because they will all move ahead by 1.

Comment: Two things to consider. (1) *Use a debugger*. (2) When doing (1), watch carefully and consider that, after deleting  whatever is in position '2', what *was* in position '3' is no longer. It has shifted due to the prior deleting. Therefore, counting to '3' makes no sense whatsoever. Think about that.

Comment: @interjay thank you, it no longer throws a segmentation fault now! Although it still keeps adding the second element in the returned list.

Comment: The code is not complete how are `Node`, `addLast()` and `delete()` defined. Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Further indent your code right!

Comment: @AndreKampling I edited it now, sorry.

Comment: @ Gaurav Sehgal: Probably not the cause for a "segfault"; but a `delete` that pretends to delete arbitrary nodes but cannot delete the first one is another source of errors. And the code let's one assume that `n==0` would be a valid input.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by WhozCraig, counting from the beginning does not make sense once you have delete one single element.

But you could simply iterate the list one element at a time counting the number of elements iterated from the beginning and simply either remove an element if its index is prime or just skip it. `primes` would just become:

```
Node* primes(Node* list) {
    Node* temp = list;
    int i = 1;                   // trick: we know 1 is not prime so skip it
    while (temp->next != NULL) { // and it is easier to delete next element than current one
        i++;
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            delete(1, temp);        // delete if index is prime
        }
        else temp = temp->next;     // else skip
    }
    return list;                    // done with it...
}
```

Comment: I suggest use DP for `IsPrime(i)`